# How to assign ID's from one table to dates in another table in SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm

I'm new to C# and have this problem that have been struggling my mind for days:

I have two tables in SQL Server:

**EMPLOYEE**:

```
ID|NAME|
--------
1|James|
2|Brad|
3|Alex|
```

**Table2**:

```
IDEmployee| DATE
-------------------
null      | 02/12/2014
null      | 02/14/2014
null      | 02/16/2014
null      | 02/18/2014
null      | 02/20/2014
null      | 02/22/2014
```

and I want the second table to be like this:

```
IDEmployee | DATE
-------------------
    1      | 02/12/2014
    2      | 02/14/2014
    3      | 02/16/2014
    1      | 02/18/2014
    2      | 02/20/2014
    3      | 02/22/2014
```

The first table is filled with employee's names and their ID's the second one is filled with dates, I need to assign each to date an employee's ID, some ideas or suggestions would be great, thanks for your time.

Comment: Er.. how do you know which date is for which employee?

Comment: the order of the assigned dates for each employee will be the same as they are in employees table, for example, if i had an 4th employee, his assigned date would be 02/18/2014... and the 02/20/2014 would be for 1rst employee and so on..

Comment: OK. Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Why don't you to that directly in SQL?

Comment: @thepirat000 thanks for asking, that's because i need this to be done automatically, without assigning each date manually, it can be done executing a query from C# o running some C# code

Comment: But, the data is on the database, and at the end you need to update the database. Still do not understand why to do it in C#. By the way, does "table2" have a primary key?

Comment: Doing something directly in SQL doesn't mean assigning each date manually, it means executing a SQL query instead of running a C# application that executes a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to cycle between employees, assigning the dates by order going back to the first one after the last...

basically a simple loop would do the trick since you don't really need to match any data.

Are you looking to code this in C# or SQL ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. But if i delete an employee, i would get an unmatching IDEmployee on the Table2, that's why i need to cycle between employee's IDs, im looking to code this on C# thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use SQL >= 2005, and that the field *[Date]* on *TABLE2* is a primary key, you can do that in T-SQL:

```
With EMPLOYEE_ORDERED
AS
(
    Select ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 0)) As [Order]
    From EMPLOYEE
),
TABLE2_ORDERED
AS
(
    Select IDEmployee, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 0)) As [Order], [Date]
    From TABLE2
)
Update T2
Set  IDEmployee = EO.ID
from TABLE2 T2, TABLE2_ORDERED T2O, EMPLOYEE_ORDERED EO
Where EO.[Order] = (T2O.[Order]-1) % (SELECT COUNT(1) From EMPLOYEE) + 1
And T2.[Date] = T2O.[Date]
```